# Unable to convert and save excel file into PDF using Python

Tags: python, openpyxl, win32com, file-conversion

I am trying to import excel files and converting them into PDF using Python. I tried using win32com library but the saved file is not good. Saved PDF only contains first few columns from excel.

Code:-

```py
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
o.Visible = False
wb_path = r'c:\user\desktop\sample.xls'
wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
ws_index_list = [1,4,5] #say you want to print these sheets
path_to_pdf = r'C:\user\desktop\sample.pdf'
wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)
```

Comment: We need to see your code for us to show where the problem is.

Comment: Hi, Justin I have added the code, which I am using. Please check

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path? On my windows PC the path to the desktop is `C:\Users\<my username>\Desktop`.

Comment: There is no issue with directory path.